# Out of Memory Exception In C#

Tags: memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm attempting to construct a suffix trie, and due to strict requirements it must be indexed in memory.

EDIT: The problem is not the tree itself, but actually the way I was reading the file.

Comment: My guess is that the file is too big and you don't have enough memory.  Increase the max heap size and run it again.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649722/how-to-refer-to-children-in-a-tree-with-millions-of-nodes and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670080/memory-exception-in-c-sharp

Comment: How large is large? And how do you index the file?

Comment: Either you're doing the same homework or this is [a repost](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9670080/) under a different account. Much better question, but you should have edited the old one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're passing the entire text file as a single `string` you could easily run into an out of memory exception with your first loop!

```
// imagine if s.Length was 100k or so
for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
{
    AddString(s.Substring(i, s.Length-i));
}
```

When reading the file to construct the trie, you'll need to split each line and probably normalize the characters:

```
string line;
while (null != (line = reader.ReadLine()))
{
    string[] parts = line.Split(' ', ',', '.', '!', '\t', '?'); // naive
    foreach (string part in parts)
    {
        if (part.Length > 0)
        {
            // make each string uppercase so as to avoid Hello and hello being
            // two trie entries
            trie.AddSuffix(part.ToUpperInvariant());
        }
    }
}
```

For example (on the output from `dir /b c:\windows`):

```
A
 D
  D
   I
    N
     S
  E
   D
 P
  P
   C
    O
     M
      P
       A
        T
   P
    A
     T
      C
       H
...
```

---

To appropriately handle larger files, a more compact trie structure would be desirable. I would just have unshared suffixes stored in a separate dictionary:

```
// If you add a character, but there is no entry in m_children
// just park the tail end of it here
Dictionary<char, string> m_tails;
```

You would then move the per character logic to your `AddString` of the `SuffixNode`:

```
public void AddString(string s)
{
    if (s.Length == 0) return;

    char c = s[0];
    if (m_children.ContainsKey(c))
    {
        if (s.Length > 1) m_children[c].AddString(s.Substring(1));
    }
    else if (m_tails.ContainsKey(c))
    {
        SuffixNode node = new SuffixNode();
        node.AddString(m_tails[c]);
        if (s.Length > 1) node.AddString(s.Substring(1));

        m_children.Add(c, node);
        m_tails.Remove(c);
    }
    else
    {
        m_tails.Add(c, s.Length > 1 ? s.Substring(1) : "");
    }
}
```

Now you have a much more compact version of the trie, which will greatly decrease the number of child `SuffixNode`s created for any given corpus. Returning to the `dir /b c:\windows` example, we can see a practical reduction in nodes:

```
A
 P
  P
   COMPAT
   PATCH
  I
 T
  I
   O
    N
     S
...
```

At this point your trie has a more efficient representation. You're left with determining how to deal with terminal node representations in order to ensure lookups are accurate.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I tried implementing what you've suggested, however only a small bit of the text file is actually read. Any idea why?

Comment: I get all of the file being available in the trie and am able to read in rather large files using your code. I've yet to establish the limit however.

Comment: One thing you should note is that your current usage of a `Dictionary` is efficient in terms of lines of code, but likely inefficient in terms of memory representation once you get into a large corpus.

Comment: I can't understand what's going on - I'm using the code you suggested for reading the file, yet it only reads the last few sentences of the file!

Comment: I used your code almost verbatim (instead I use `AddString(s.Substring(i))`). Did you declare `trie` inside the while loop?

Comment: No, trie is not declared there. It's quite strange because it **should** be working. Thanks for your answer though, this looks like it's the problem

Comment: Using the more compact representation I was able to process a 12MB text file (`dir /b/s c:\windows`) in a working set of ~2.7GB. Hardly efficient, but it ran to completion.